# Better than if else statements: Referring to list element by name instead?

Tags: r

I have a list called `behaviourList` that has multiple sublists and each one has a different number of element, e.g.

```
dput(behaviourList[[1]])
c("In", "FarPatient", "Out")
```

whilst behaviourList[[2]] might look like this:

```
dput(behaviourList[[2]])
c("In", "FarPatient", "NearPatient", "Equipment", "Equipment", 
"Equipment", "FarPatient", "Equipment", "FarPatient", "Out")
```

I have another vector called `surfConc` which contains all the possible surfaces in a hospital room that might be in behaviourList (a total of 7 different ones), and a contamination level on each of them.

```
dput(surfConc)
structure(list(In = 3.8, FarPatient = 0.4, 
    Out = 4.3, NearPatient = 3.2, Equipment = 2.4, 
    Patient = 0.1, HygieneInside = 6.7), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

I would like to sum the values in `surfConc` that appear in `behaviourList[[1]]`, but in a particular order.

e.g. C(t) is what is on my finger after any given surface contact n:

```
C(n)=C(n-1)+runif(1)*(C(n-1)-SurfConc(behaviourList[[1]][n])))
```

how can I do this without using an `if else` statement such as this monstrosity?

```
for(n in 1:NROW(behaviourList[[1]]){
    if(behaviourList[[1]][z]=="In"){
    resulTEMP = surfConc$In} else if (behaviourList[[1]][z]=="NearPatient"){
    resulTEMP = surfConc$NearPatient}else if (behaviourList[[1]][z]=="Equipment"){
    resulTEMP = surfConc$Equipment}else if (behaviourList[[1]][z]=="Patient"){
    resulTEMP = surfConc$Patient}else if (behaviourList[[1]][z]=="FarPatient"){
    resulTEMP = surfConc$Patient}else if (behaviourList[[1]][z]=="Out"){
    resulTEMP = surfConc$Out}
    }
result=result+resulTEMP*runif(1)
}
```

BehaviourList is very big so I will probably use a for statement to cycle through all the other behaviours in it but just a little help with this bit would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
set.seed(5)
lapply(behaviourList, function(x) sum(surfConc[x] * runif(x)))

[[1]]
[1] 4.977468

[[2]]
[1] 11.13312
```

Note you have an error in your loop where`surfConc$Patient` is used a second time instead of `surfConc$FarPatient`.  If we fix that then the output is the same as the loop:

```
result
[1] 4.977468
```

Comment: Thank you for such a quick answer. I realised I had made a mistake in my original question and that the order of adding up the concentrations mattered as per the recurrence relationship I added a few minutes after you answered. I'm sorry to confuse folks.

Comment: Perhaps you can update the question with an example that walks through your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to compute contamination of finger tips after several surface contacts according to the *recursive* formula

C<sub>n</sub> = C<sub>n-1</sub> + R<sub>n</sub> * (C<sub>n-1</sub> - S<sub>n</sub>)

where
C<sub>n</sub> is the contamination level after *n* surface contacts,
S<sub>n</sub> is the contamination level of the *n*-th surface touched,
R<sub>n</sub> is a uniformly distributed random number

Each list element of `behaviourList` documents the surfaces which were touched by an individual in the course of an activity. The contamination level of each surface is stored in a separate data.frame `surfConc`.

There are two issues to solve here

1. Computing the recursion while
2. using the contamination levels of surfaces in the given order

### Computing on the list

```
c0 <- 10
set.seed(5)
lapply(
  behaviourList, 
  function(x) { 
    result <- c0
    for (i in x) {
      result <- result + runif(1) * (result - surfConc[1, i])
    } 
    result
  }
)
```

> ```
> [[1]]
> [1] 31.84552
>
> [[2]]
> [1] 264.7798
> ```

Here, `c0` is the initial contamination level of the fingers before touching any of the recorded surfaces. `lapply()` iterates over the activities while the for loop computes the recursive formula.

The output is again a list.

### Computing on rectangular data objects

When I came across the question, my first impression was that *deeply nested ifelse()* look like a good candidate for joining with a look-up table. (At a second look, I understood that the crucial point is the recursive operation on list elements.)

Personally, I prefer to store and process data in rectangular data objects, such as SQL tables or R data frames. See [Hadley Wickham's article on *Tidy Data*](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v59/i10/paper), e.g.

So, this is what I would do if I would be assigned this task:

1. Turn `behaviourList` into a data frame
2. Turn `surfConc` into a look-up table
3. Join both objects
4. Compute the recursion

#### Prepare the data

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr) # piping used to improve readbility
behaviourTbl <- 
  reshape2::melt(behaviourList) %>% 
  setDT() %>% 
  setnames(c("surface", "id"))

behaviourTbl
```

> ```
>         surface id
>  1:          In  1
>  2:  FarPatient  1
>  3:         Out  1
>  4:          In  2
>  5:  FarPatient  2
>  6: NearPatient  2
>  7:   Equipment  2
>  8:   Equipment  2
>  9:   Equipment  2
> 10:  FarPatient  2
> 11:   Equipment  2
> 12:  FarPatient  2
> 13:         Out  2
> ```

```
surfConcTbl <- 
  surfConc %>% 
  setDT() %>% 
  melt(measure.vars = names(.), variable.name = "surface", value.name = "concentration")

surfConcTbl
```

> ```
>          surface concentration
> 1:            In           3.8
> 2:    FarPatient           0.4
> 3:           Out           4.3
> 4:   NearPatient           3.2
> 5:     Equipment           2.4
> 6:       Patient           0.1
> 7: HygieneInside           6.7
> ```

#### Join and aggregate

```
c0 <- 10
set.seed(5)
surfConcTbl[behaviourTbl, on = .(surface)][
  , {
    result <- c0
    for (i in seq(.N)) {
      result <- result + runif(1) * (result - concentration[i])
    }
    list(result = result)
  }, by = id]
```

which returns a data.table instead of a list.

> ```
>    id    result
> 1:  1  31.84552
> 2:  2 264.77983
> ```

Here, `id` identifies the list elements in the original `behaviourList`.